# Build python package for CLI script

Tags: python-3.x, build, package, pypi, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to build my first python package and publish it to PyPi. My goal is to provide a certain feature via CLI so the final user can install it via pip like `pip3 install my-package` and use it directly from the terminal like `my-package -fa first_argument -sa second_argument`.

Let's say my package is called `fp-test-package`. I made a mockup of my project folder structure that you can find here https://github.com/fabiopipitone/fp-test-package.

In the mockup I also inserted as requirements one of the packages required in the real project (tqdm) and keep the exact same convention (hyphen on external folder and github repo, underscores for internal packages, same position and import for helpers and utils and so on). This way, if it works on the mockup it must work on the real project.

Here's the directory strucure of the project

```
fp-test-package
├── fp_test_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── fp_test_package.py
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── arguments_checkers.py
│   │   ├── csv_handlers.py
│   │   └── utility_functions.py
│   └── utils
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── CustomLogger.py
│       └── TqdmLoggingHandler.py
├── LICENSE
├── README.rst
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── docs
└── tests
```

Here's the setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
with open("README.rst", "r") as fh:
  long_description = fh.read()

setup( 
  name ='fp-test-package', 
  version ='0.0.1', 
  description='Simple test building a CLI tool package',
  long_description=long_description,
  long_description_content_type='text/x-rst', 
  license ='GPLv2', 
  packages = find_packages(), 
  entry_points ={ 
    'console_scripts': [ 
      'fp_test_package = fp_test_package.py:main'
    ] 
  }, 
  classifiers =( 
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3", 
    "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v2", 
    "Operating System :: Linux", 
  ), 
  keywords ='test packaging fabiopipitone', 
  install_requires = ['tqdm>=4.49.0'], 
  zip_safe = False
)
```

I tried following couple of howtos about how to build and publish a CLI python package, then I tried with `sudo python3 setup.py install` from inside the `fp-test-package` directory (same level of the setup.py). It seems to install the package (I can find the entry `fp-test-package==0.0.1` in the `pip3 freeze`) but if I try `fp-test-package` in the terminal it returns `fp-test-package: command not found`, if I try `fp_test_package` it returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/fp_test_package", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('fp-test-package==0.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'fp_test_package')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2854, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2445, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2451, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fp_test_package.py'
```

Then I went with `sudo pip3 uninstall fp_test_package`, which successfully uninstalled the package. I deleted the previously created `build`, `dist` and `fp_test_package.egg-info` directories and tried with `pip3 install -e .` (again from inside the `fp-test-package`). It created the `fp_test_package.egg-info` directory but again, running `fp_test_package` in the console it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/fp_test_package", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('fp-test-package==0.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'fp_test_package')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2854, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2445, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2451, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fp_test_package.py'
```

Now, what am I missing? I'd like to simply package and install it so that when the user type `fp-test-package` or `fp_test_package` it returns the error about the `--export_path` argument being required (means the script's correctly started) like when I call it from the console:

```
$ python3 fp_test_package/fp_test_package.py
                                
usage: fp_test_package.py [-h] -ep EXPORT_PATH [-sa SECOND_ARGUMENT] [-ta THIRD_ARGUMENT]
fp_test_package.py: error: the following arguments are required: -ep/--export_path
```

How can I do it?

EDIT:
I noticed what @Dustin then pointed out about the setup.py. In fact, a colleague of mine PRed the dummy repo changing the `console_scripts` part.
Now, on my colleague machine everything seems to work as expected. On mine, after pulling the repo and rerun the `python3 setup.py install`, when calling `fp_test_package` from the console, it returns the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/fp_test_package", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('fp-test-package==0.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'fp_test_package')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 490, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2854, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2445, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2451, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/bin/fp_test_package.py", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('fp-test-package==0.0.1', 'fp_test_package.py')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 667, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1452, in run_script
    raise ResolutionError(
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: Script 'scripts/fp_test_package.py' not found in metadata at '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fp_test_package-0.0.1-py3.8.egg/EGG-INFO'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I eventually found the problem on my specific case. What caused that cryptic error when installing with `python3 setup.py install`

`pkg_resources.ResolutionError: Script 'scripts/fp_test_package.py' not found in metadata at '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fp_test_package-0.0.1-py3.8.egg/EGG-INFO'`

or the equivalent error when installing with `pip3 install .`

`pkg_resources.ResolutionError: Script 'scripts/fp_test_package.py' not found in metadata at '/home/fabio/Desktop/test_python_package/fp-test-package/fp_test_package-0.0.1-py3.8.egg/EGG-INFO'`

was the absence in the $PATH variable of the required path to properly launch the script.

Summing up, what I did was:

- editing the `setup.py` file according to the Dustin suggestions about the `console_scripts`
- building and installing the package running `pip3 install .` (or `pip3 install -e .` if you want the editable version) from inside the `fp-test-package` folder.
- checking where the binary of the script was created with `which fp_test_package` (in my case `/home/fabio/.local/bin/fp_test_package`)
- adding that `path` to the $PATH env var (in my `.bashrc` - and `.zshrc` since I use `zsh` - I added a line `export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"`)

Now everything works as expected.
I won't delete the [correct version of the repo](https://github.com/fabiopipitone/fp-test-package), so if anyone wants to use a working skeleton to start a project, it can be found there.

Answer (score 1):

Your `setup.py` has:

```py
  entry_points ={ 
    'console_scripts': [ 
      'fp_test_package = fp_test_package.py:main'
    ] 
  },
```

This is the equivalent of the following import:

```py
from fp_test_package.py import main as fp_test_package
```

The problem is that you don't have a `fp_test_package.py` module, you have a `fp_test_package` module (directory with an `__init__.py` file) that contains a `fp_test_package` submodule (module names don't include the extension).

Assuming your `fp_test_package.py` file defines a `main` function, you could change this to:

```py
  entry_points ={ 
    'console_scripts': [ 
      'fp_test_package = fp_test_package.fp_test_package:main'
    ] 
  },
```

Or you could move your `main` function to `fp_test_package/__init__.py`, so it could be:

```py
  entry_points ={ 
    'console_scripts': [ 
      'fp_test_package = fp_test_package:main'
    ] 
  },
```

Comment: I noticed what you pointed out and a colleague of mine PRed the git repo. After the merge you can notice the change in the `setup.py` with the same solution you posted. What is funny is that now everything works on my colleague machine, but after I pulled the new version and rerun the setup with `python3 setup.py install`, when trying to use the package with `fp_test_package` from the console, it returns:

```
...
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: Script 'scripts/fp_test_package.py' not found in metadata at '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fp_test_package-0.0.1-py3.8.egg/EGG-INFO'
```

Comment: You need to fully uninstall the package and reinstall it, preferably with `pip install .` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by fully unistall it? I went with `sudo pip3 uninstall fp_test_package` and then `sudo rm -rf fp_test_package.egg-info dist build` to remove the created directories. Then I tried with both `sudo python3 setup.py install` and `pip3 install -e .` (one first, then delete everythin and try the other) and both return same error. I even tried with a venv. Same error. After installing, running `pip3 list`, only the line of my package (`fp-test-package        0.0.1`), has a `Location` column value (on my colleague's machine it is empty). Does it mean anything?

Comment: Does `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/fp_test_package-0.0.1-py3.8.egg` still exist after you uninstall it?

Comment: It doesn't. After `pip3 uninstall fp_test_package` and all the `rm -rf`, if I run `find . -name fp_test*` as a sudo user from `/` I only get `./home/fabio/Desktop/test_python_package/fp-test-package/fp_test_package` and `./home/fabio/Desktop/test_python_package/fp-test-package/fp_test_package/fp_test_package.py`, then the only references to `fp_test*` are those of the `fp-test-package` folder.
Now, if I run `pip3 install -e .` the Location column of `fp_test_package` line in the `pip3 list` shows `/home/fabio/Desktop/test_python_package/fp-test-package`.